# C Doubly linked list with structure

Tags: c, struct, doubly-linked-list

I'm doing a doubly linked list. As far as I know it is working but came here to make sure and to see if I'm doing the correct way.

On the other side, when I made this I came upon to other questions not related to doubly linked list but with structures and "visibility" between C files. If you understand that I should create other questions to this two other doubt's please tell. Otherwise feel free to enlighten me.

On my file1.c I have this:

**CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct team{
    char *name;
    char *teamPlace;
}Team;

typedef struct nodeTeam{
    int numberOfTeams;
    Team team;
    struct nodeTeam *next;
    struct nodeTeam *prev;
}NodeTeam;

int createsListOfTeams(NodeTeam **head, NodeTeam **tail);
void printListOfTeams(NodeTeam *listofTeams);
int addNodeTeamsSorted(NodeTeam *head, NodeTeam **tail, Team team);

int main()
{
    NodeTeam *headEquipas,*tailEquipas;
    Team eq;
    /*Creates the doubly linked list*/
    if(createsListOfTeams(&headEquipas,&tailEquipas)){
        printf("\nError\n");
        return 0;
    }
    /*Add the teams to the doubly linked list. At the end, all teams will be sorted by name*/
    eq.name = "D team";
    eq.teamPlace = "D team place";
    if (addNodeTeamsSorted(headEquipas,&tailEquipas,eq)){
        printf("\nError\n");
        return 0;
    }

    eq.name = "A team";
    eq.teamPlace = "A team place";
    if (addNodeTeamsSorted(headEquipas,&tailEquipas,eq)){
        printf("\nError\n");
        return 0;
    }

    eq.name = "C team";
    eq.teamPlace = "C team place";
    if (addNodeTeamsSorted(headEquipas,&tailEquipas,eq)){
        printf("\nError\n");
        return 0;
    }

    eq.name = "B team";
    eq.teamPlace = "B team place";
    if (addNodeTeamsSorted(headEquipas,&tailEquipas,eq)){
        printf("\nError\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /*Will print all the teams*/
    printListOfTeams(headEquipas);

    return 0;
}
```

And on my file2.c I have this

**CODE**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    typedef struct team{
        char *name;
        char *teamPlace;
    }Team;

    typedef struct nodeTeam{
        int numberOfTeams;
        Team team;
        struct nodeTeam *next;
        struct nodeTeam *prev;
    }NodeTeam;

    /*Add the teams to the doubly linked list. At the end, all teams will be sorted by name*/
    int createsListOfTeams(NodeTeam **head, NodeTeam **tail){
        (*head) = (NodeTeam *)malloc(sizeof(NodeTeam));

        if ((*head) == NULL){
            return -1;
        }
        (*head)->numberOfTeams = 0;
        (*head)->team.teamPlace = "";
        (*head)->team.name = "";
        (*head)->next = NULL;
        (*head)->prev = NULL;

        *tail = *head;
        return 0;
    }

    /*Creates the doubly linked list*/
    int addNodeTeamsSorted(NodeTeam *head, NodeTeam **tail, Team team){
        NodeTeam *no,*listIni;


        no = (NodeTeam*) malloc(sizeof(NodeTeam));
        if (no == NULL){
            return -1;
        }

        /*copy of my list*/
        listIni = head;

        no->team = team;
        /*to see is it's the first element of my list*/
        if(head->numberOfTeams == 0)
        {
            no->next = head->next;
            no->prev = head;
            head->next = no;
            *tail = no;

        }
        else{ /*If not the first element*/
            head = head->next;
            while(head->prev != *tail && strcmp(head->team.name,no->team.name) < 0 && strcmp((*tail)->team.name,no->team.name)>0){
                head = head->next;
                (*tail) = (*tail)->prev;
            }
            if(strcmp(head->team.name,no->team.name) >= 0 || head->prev == *tail){
                no->next = head;
                no->prev = head->prev;
                (head->prev)->next = no;
                head->prev = no;

            }
            else if(strcmp((*tail)->team.name,no->team.name) <= 0){
                no->next = (*tail)->next;
                no->prev = (*tail);
                (*tail)->next = no;
                *tail = no;

            }
        }

        /*Updates the number of element of the list*/
        head = listIni;
        head->numberOfTeams++;

        return 0;
    }
    /*Prints my lists*/
    void printListOfTeams(NodeTeam *listofTeams){
        printf("|   number of teams %22d |\n",listofTeams->numberOfTeams);
        printf("|      team name      |        team place      |\n");
        printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
        listofTeams = listofTeams->next;
        while (listofTeams != NULL){
            printf("| %-21s | %-22s |\n",listofTeams->team.name,listofTeams->team.teamPlace);
            listofTeams = listofTeams->next;
        }
        printf("--------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    }
```

So here are my tree questions:

**Q1** - Is this the correct way to implement a doubly linked list with an head and a tail pointing to the beginning and the end of the list respectively?

**Q2** - Why do declare on both of my files the `struct team` and the `struct nodeTeam`? Since they are all in the same project should't the declaration be "visible" to all of the files on my project?

**Q3** - In `struct team`why do I have to declare `char *name` instead of `char name[31]`?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "project" in C, only "translation units".

Comment: Q1 seems ok, but mostly nonenglish names makes me unwilling to check carefully, sorry :-). Q2 place it into a header file. Q3 noone knows why you have to.. quick answer is that you don't.

Comment: @keltar. Sorry. Forgot to translate :( Now its translated

Comment: +1 for the effort to write the question correctly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some edits after your previous comments and after analyzed your code more carefully.
I wrongly interpreted one remark about the head and tail items and though you were designing a circular list

1. I took the time to copy / paste / compile your code. While it is almost working I must say that I would have designed in another way by

   - moving the `prev`/ `next` pointers into the `struct team`
   - and replacing the `team` member of `nodeTeam` by a `head` pointer to the first `team`.

   That would have the following benefits :

   - prevent a useless waste of space for the `numberOfTeams` that is duplicated for each `nodeTeams` but only meaningful to the first
   - avoid a confusion between the conceptual `head` and the actual first team

   By adding the value of the pointers in the team list with

   `printf("| %-21s | %-22s | %p - p=%p n=%p\n",listofTeams->team.name, listofTeams->team.teamPlace, listofTeams, listofTeams->prev, listofTeams->next);`

   I noticed a possible bug in your linking :

   > | A team                | A team place           | 0x101d00980 - p=0x101d00920 n=0x101d009e0
   >
   > | B team                | B team place           | 0x101d009e0 - p=0x101d00980 n=0x101d009b0
   >
   > | C team                | C team place           | 0x101d009b0 - p=0x101d00980 n=0x101d00950
   >
   > | D team                | D team place           | 0x101d00950 - p=0x101d009b0 n=0x0

   You can see that next pointers are ok, but the prev pointers show **suspicious duplicates** (0x101d00920 is indeed the 'head').

   If you trace the execution of your code and check what it done in `addNodeTeamsSorted()` You could notice that everything is ok **until step 3** (addition of team C, after existing A & D) :

   - due to the weird double modification of both head and tail to find the place to insert the new item, head an tail are crossing: tail actually points to 'A' and head to 'D' (dont forget that while `head` is `Nodeteam *` and its modification won't be propagated outside of the function, `tail` is a `Nodeteam **`, thus when it is changed into the caller and for the next call it will be wrong
   - **in the step 4** (addition of 'B') in the `else if` part of the test, you change properly the prev/next of `no`, the next of (*tail) **but not** prev of `no->next` so you have

     - 'B' -> next = 'C' : OK
     - 'B' -> prev = 'A' : OK
     - *tail (='A') -> next = 'B' : OK
     - 'C' -> prev still = 'A' : **WRONG**
2. This is not like that that the compiler is thinking. He only processes compilational units, one at a time. What is not declared in the .c and the different included .h will remain unknown. If you want to share the structs declarations between 2 modules, and to prevent errors in code maintenance, cut the typedefs and put them in a common header file (e.g. `equipa.h`) that will be included in both .c
3. You have to use `char*` instead of `char[]` because in your `main()` in file1.c you are making direct assignments from literal strings and the compiler won't let you assign a literal string to a char array. If you wan to use `char[]` instead change your

   `eq.nome = "D team";`

   by string copying like

   `strcpy(eq.nome, "D team");`

   of course, I am only dealing with the concept, actually you should take care that the string that will be copied are not longer than the buffer by using `strncpy()` and `sizeof(eq.nome)`

Comment: Thanks. There is a problem with my linking. Don't know ho to solve. List should be like this. The head element of my list as `numberOfTeams` with the value of `4` (the A,B,C and D teams). `Team team` is with `name` and `teamPlace` as `""`. The next pointer, points to `A team` and the prev pointer points to `NULL`. The `A team` next points to `B team`, the `B team`next points to `C team`, `C team` next points to `D team` and since `D team` is the last element of my list, `D team` next should point to `NULL`.

Comment: `A team` prev points to the head element of my list, the `B team` prev points to `A team`, `C team` prev points to `B team` and since `D team` is the last element of my list, `D team` prev should point to `C team`. So, as you kindly demonstrated with your print debugging, there is a problem my `prev`linking in the middle of my list. If the address of my head element is `0x101d00920` the `A team` `prev` is OK

Comment: I have looked at it more deeply and corrected my explanation on point 1